# how to add a new library to vs2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I want to use libcrafter in my program, so I want to include the crafter.h in vs2010..

I have downloaded the library for this and now I have a folder named "crafter2.tar.gz"..but I

don't know how should I add it to vs as a library..how can I do it in vs2010? can any one

introduce me a useful link?

Comment: Permanently or just for that project? You can add the path you extract it to to the project properties (on the compile tab I think) or globally under Tools, Options, Directories (or similar). That's if you've got headers and binaries, though; if you need to build it you can also add the project that builds the library to your solution and add it as a dependency to the project that's using it.

Comment: thanks for answer, how should I add the project that build the library....you know I have a folder called crafter-.2.tar.gz and I don't know any thing a bout the files in that folder, but I know I should add it to my project as a new library, what should I do with this folder?

Comment: Maybe you should first figure out how to unpack a tarball. Did you try reading the instructions?

Comment: which instruction do you mean? I found some instructions in internet to add a library to visual studio and I found I should do it in properties of my project,for example in link tab in general......but in one case it need one or more ".lib" file, but I couldn't find it, in that folder.

Comment: This library has a dependency on other libraries, it can only work on Linux.  Forget about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Unzip the File you downloaded using some software like 7-zip until you get folder with no extensions(*.tar,*gz etc)).

2) Compile the code to get a static library(*.lib)

3) Add the library to Project>Properties>linker>Additional Dependancies

4) Add the path to Project>Properties>linker>General>Additional Library Directories

Comment: how should I compile the code? it is a folder with a lot of files, such that the .h files such .cpp files and such ".ac" ".m4" ".in" and ..... how should I compile these files?how should  I add them to my project?

Comment: ac etc. are for GNU autotools which help you build this on Linux or other Unixes. It's likely written for Linux then and you may have to make code changes to get it to compile on Windows. It doesn't sound like you know enough to do this - like Hans says it may be simplest to try something else.